# Dynamic/Customized Week Number

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let us say there is a table which stores data for student's attendance for classes. The student only need to attend each class once weekly. Hinging on the ***days_diff*** column, we decide which weeks the student should get credited for. As usual, each week has 7 days and the end of the week (in days) is divisible by 7. There is a different case for Week 3 in my scenario, whenever the **week_3** is attended, the week ends at that attendance date and **week_4** is started the next day.

I am using postgreSQL 11.4!

```
select * from students_data
```

| student_name | class_subject | registration_date | attendance_date | days_diff | week_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-18 | 3 | week_1 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-24 | 9 | week_2 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-11-01 | 17 | week_3 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-11-10 | 26 | week_4 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-11-20 | 36 | week_6 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-10-25 | 5 | week_1 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-02 | 13 | week_2 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-08 | 19 | week_3 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-23 | 34 | week_5 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-30 | 41 | week_6 |

Desired Week Breakdown:

```
student    days_in_week      week_number
Frank         1-7               week_1
Frank         8-14              week_2
Frank        15-17              week_3     <-----week_3 shakes up the week breakdown
Frank        18-24              week_4
Frank        25-31              week_5........
Danny         1-7               week_1
Danny         8-14              week_2
Danny        15-19              week_3     <----week_3 shakes up the week breakdown
Danny        20-26              week_4
Danny        27-33              week_5........
```

Requested: **new_week_num** column

| student_name | class_subject | registration_date | attendance_date | days_diff | week_num | new_week_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-18 | 3 | week_1 | week_1 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-24 | 9 | week_2 | week_2 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-11-01 | 17 | week_3 | week_3 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-11-10 | 26 | week_4 | week_5 |
| Frank | Chemistry | 2021-10-15 | 2021-11-20 | 36 | week_6 | week_7 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-10-25 | 5 | week_1 | week_1 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-02 | 13 | week_2 | week_2 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-08 | 19 | week_3 | week_3 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-23 | 34 | week_5 | week_6 |
| Danny | Physics | 2021-10-20 | 2021-11-30 | 41 | week_6 | week_7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 : cte and JOIN**

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT student_name, class_subject, registration_date, days_diff
  FROM your_table
 WHERE week_num = 'week_3'
)
SELECT t.*
     , CASE 
         WHEN t.days_diff <= l.days_diff
         THEN t.week_num
         ELSE 'week_' || (3 + ceil((t.days_diff - l.days_diff)/7.0)) :: text
       END AS new_week_num
  FROM your_table AS t
  LEFT JOIN list AS l
    ON t.student_name = l.student_name
   AND t.class_subject = l.class_subject
   AND t.registration_date = l.registration_date
```

**Solution 2 : LATERAL JOIN**

```
SELECT t.*
     , CASE 
         WHEN t.days_diff <= l.days_diff
         THEN t.week_num
         ELSE 'week_' || (3 + ceil((t.days_diff - l.days_diff)/7.0)) :: text
       END AS new_week_num
  FROM your_table AS t
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     ( SELECT l.days_diff
         FROM your_table AS l
        WHERE l.student_name = t.student_name
         AND l.class_subject = t.class_subject
         AND l.registration_date = t.registration_date
         AND l.week_num = 'week_3'
       LIMIT 1
     ) AS l
```

**Solution 3 : window function**

```
SELECT t.*
     , CASE 
         WHEN days_diff <= (array_agg(days_diff) FILTER (WHERE week_num = 'week_3') OVER w)[1]
         THEN week_num
         ELSE 'week_' || (3 + ceil((t.days_diff - (array_agg(days_diff) FILTER (WHERE week_num = 'week_3') OVER w)[1])/7.0)) :: text
       END AS new_week_num
  FROM your_table AS t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY student_name, class_subject, registration_date ORDER BY days_diff ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

test in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=65c74b02ffec741e2245f81c00fa7630)